# Enter Key not working while implementing DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, documentfilter

I have implemented a document filter by inheriting the orignal `DocumentFilter` class and overriding it's `insert` and `replace` methods. It is responding to all keys except the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I mean when ever I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should go to the next line in my `JTextPane` but it is not doing that. So how can I make my `Enter` key work properly?

**Code**

```
class UrduFilter extends DocumentFilter {
//My urdu filter overriding insertString and replace
    char urduChar;
    String urduString;

    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterByPass fb, int offset,
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        System.out.println("\n" + text);
        urduChar = Translate.translateToUrdu(text.charAt(0));
        urduString = Character.toString(urduChar);
        fb.insertString(offset, urduString, attr);
    }

    //no need to override remove(): inherited version allows all removals

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterByPass fb, int offset, int length, 
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        urduChar = Translate.translateToUrdu(text.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(text + " ... " + text.charAt(0));
        urduString = Character.toString(urduChar);
        fb.replace(offset, length, urduString, attr);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You must be definitely doing something custom in `actionPerformed` method related to the `JTextPane` that is changing the default behavior. Please post the relevant piece of code.

Comment: public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
      String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
   
 
   //for typing urdu from keyboard.
   urduChar = Translate.translateToUrdu(text.charAt(0));
   
   
  
   System.out.println(text+"---"+text.charAt(0));
   urduString = Character.toString(urduChar);
       fb.replace(offset, length, urduString, attr);
 
  }

Comment: @Muhammed, DocumentFilter does not affect Enter key. Do you have a key handling method somewhere in  use ?

Comment: No have'nt yet, but i can implement some keylistener. But wait a minute, does i have to add a keyListener or an actionListener?. And what i should do further with the either case?.

Comment: I mean how can i make the caret to move to next line either with keyListener or actionListener?

Comment: You should not use a KeyListener and a JTextPane does not support an ActionListener. You should be using Key Bindings.

Answer (score 3):

What does `Translate.translateToUrdu(char)` do with enter key character ( 13 ) ? 
That seems to be the issue since you say that you do not use an `ActionListener`

Comment: Translate.translateToUrdu recieves an english character and returns an urdu one. But i had done some mechanisem that when ever the enter key character (i guess its 10) is pressed then do not invoke this function. But it also does'nt work for me.

Comment: Here some one has told me that JTextPane doesn't support action listener.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean how can i make the caret to move to next line either with keyListener or actionListener?

By default a newline character is inserted into the Document when the Enter key is pressed.

If you don't like this behaviour then you need to replace the default Action with a custom Action of your own that places the Caret at the beginning of the next line.

Read up on [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) for more information on how to do this. When you create your custom Action you should be able to use the [Text Utilities](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) class to help you position the Carat on the next line.

Comment: That is what i am trying to ask, that i have overrided the replace and insertString() methods of documentFilter class then why the defaut newline character is not inserted into the document when the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is since you didn't post an SSCCE. Ring Bearer already asked you what your translate() method does. Gid rid of your translate code and see what happens. If it works then you know your are tranlating the newlined character incorrectly.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much, the problem was in translate(), and i have fixed it. Thank you alot.

Comment: So did you accept Ring Bearers answer for pointing you in the right direction?

Comment: i have placed a check that when ever there is an enter key, then dont invoke translate function, just add insert it to document. and if the key is other than enter, then translate it. Thats it.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use `addKeyListener()` and handle Enter key manually

Comment: -1, KeyListeners is old AWT solution. In Swing you would use Key Bindings if you want to do a specific function when the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: I just want to move caret to next line when ever an enter is pressed. I mean the normal enter key behavior in an editor.